# How does llvm IR order alloca instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I noticed that llvm IR tries to allocate spaces in the very beginning of a function regardless of the location of declaring variables inside of the function in the C source code. I want to know how these alloca instructions are ordered. My guess is first function argument and then local variables. Is there any specific rules I can refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No particular order. Also, different variables may use the same stack slot.